# Draw manipulated graphic into another graphic

Tags: c#, gdi+

I want to draw a manipulated graphic into another:

```
// I have two graphics:
var gHead = Graphics.FromImage(h);
var gBackground = Graphics.FromImage(b);

// Transform the first one
var matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.Rotate(30);
gHead.Transform = matrix;

// Write the first in the second
gBackground.DrawImage(h, 200, 0, 170, 170);
```

Output is the background img with the head img - but the head img is not rotated.

What am I missing?

Comment: What happens if you apply the transform to the gBackground object instead? `gBackground.Transform = matrix;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Transform` property of a graphics object is exactly that, a property. It does not take any action but only tells the graphics object how it should draw images.

So what you want to do is set the `Transform` property on the graphics object that you are drawing onto - in this case it should be applied to your `gBackground` object, like so...

```
gBackground.Transform = matrix;
```

then when you come round to calling the `DrawImage` method on the `gBackground` object, it will take into account the `Transform` property that you have applied.

Keep in mind that this property change will persist through all subsequent `DrawImage` calls so you may need to reset it or change the value before doing any more drawing (if you even need to)

---

To be extra clear, your final code should look like this...

```
// Just need one graphics
var gBackground = Graphics.FromImage(b);

// Apply transform to object to draw on
var matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.Rotate(30);
gBackground.Transform = matrix;

// Write the first in the second
gBackground.DrawImage(h, 200, 0, 170, 170);
```

Comment: But I don't want to rotate the background - I want to rotate the head?

Comment: @Marc: It doesn't rotate the background. It tells the graphics object that you are using for drawing that any subsequent images you draw will have a rotation applied. Try it and it should work. [See here for more information](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/Transformations0412192005054803AM/Transformations04.aspx)

Comment: Wow, yehah, it worked! Thanks a lot - so the matrix transformation is applied to all *following* `gBackground.Draw...` calls, right?

Comment: Ups, sorry, just read your previous comment. Ok, clear, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Applying a transformation to a `Graphics` object is only useful, if you are going to use that specific object. You are not doing anything with the variable `gHead`. Try applying that transformation to `gBackground`.

Comment: But I don't want to rotate the background - I want to rotate the head?

Comment: Background is not going to be rotated. Anything drawn after you apply the transformation is going to be rotated, in your case it is the image `h`.

Comment: Thank you too, you're right as well, but I can only select one answer as right - and musefan wrote more, so I took his answer :)