# Rotate an image by n degrees

Tags: c#, imaging

This seems so simple and I've done it before using the Image.RotateFlip method but this is for a predefined number of degrees (dependent upon how far the mouse has moved from its current position.

Here's what I have and I have no idea why it's not applying (the image doesn't move at all)

```
                using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(pbProfile.Image))
                {
                    g.TranslateTransform(pbProfile.Image.Width / 2f, pbProfile.Image.Height / 2f);
                    g.RotateTransform(Pixels);
                }
                pbProfile.Refresh();
```

I'm open to any and all suggestions as my brain is fried right now...

**ANSWER**

While the answer below is technically correct I found the actual solution to my problem here: [Draw manipulated graphic into another graphic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698444/draw-manipulated-graphic-into-another-graphic) this explains that I don't need to be rotating the image I'm rotating but instead the graphic I'm writing it on.

```
                Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pbProfile.Image.Width, pbProfile.Image.Height);
                using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                {
                    g.TranslateTransform(bmp.Width / 2f, bmp.Height / 2f);
                    g.RotateTransform(Pixels);
                    g.DrawImage(pbProfile.Image, 0, 0);
                }
                pbProfile.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the `g.DrawImage()` call

Comment: How would drawing an image to the picturebox help? What image would I draw?

Comment: You need to draw it to something.  A bitmap maybe?

Comment: Indeed I tried this and pointed the picturebox image to it but the image doesnt change i'll throw that code up in a bit

Comment: The selected answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14184700/how-to-rotate-image-x-degrees-in-c  Almost works.  The size returned is a bit wonky.

Comment: The big problem was the fact it's a graphics object and outside of that object it doesn't appear to be applying to the image, drawimage takes an image as a parameter so you have to have the image rotated to draw to the picturebox or draw to a new bitmap to assign to the picturebox.

Comment: I accepted your answer and I appreciate your help I've noted additional information above for those interested.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note remember that the parameter is in (float) degrees. You may get weird/unexpected results if  "Pixels" is larger than 360.

*public void RotateTransform(
    float angle
)

Parameters:angle

Type: System.Single

Angle of rotation in degrees.*